# How to get google cloud platform alert status via REST apis

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have created an alert policy in google cloud platform. I am getting the emails notifications based on the alert policy.
Now I want to configure an external custom monitoring system for this alert. I want to know the REST APIs that this monitoring system can call at after every 10-20 sec and get the status of this alert.

Please help

Comment: Please add more details about what have you tried, investigated, what errors are you receiving, what code are you implementing? The more information about this you share, the easier you can get help. If you google `GCP cloud monitoring policies api` you'll get a lot of infotmation.

Comment: I am not able to find out if there is any REST API for this or which REST api to use

Comment: Please provide information which was asked by `Joss Baron`. Without them it will be hard to tell anything. Which monitoring system you want to configure? Are you using GKE or GCE or App Engine? You are asing for GCP api or external monitoring system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use only `Cloud Monitoring`, and `Alerting Policy` you won't achieve this.

It is not possible to configure alert policies to notify (repeatedly) while the policy's conditions are met. Alert policies that are created through Google Cloud Console send a notification only when the condition is met. You can also receive a notification when the condition stops being met.

Additional information can be found in [Notifications per incident](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/concepts-indepth#number-of-notifications) documentation.

In [Cloud Monitoring API v3 - Alerting policies](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3), you can find information that only the creation of the incident is sent.

> An alerting policy is a configuration resource that describes the criteria for generating incidents and how to notify you when those incidents are created.

In general, if you want to use [Notification Channels](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options) to send notifications outside you can use [Webhooks](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#creating_channels) or [PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#pubsub).

**Note**

> Webhooks only support public endpoints. If you need notifications sent to an endpoint that isn't public, then create a Pub/Sub notification channel and configure a subscription to the Pub/Sub topic. For more information, see [Webhook notifications fail when configured for a private endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/troubleshooting-alerts#webhook).

As you didn't provide more information it's hard to say if you are not using some built-in features in 3rd party software to integrate with GCP Cloud Monitoring. One of the example is [Grafana](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/google-cloud-monitoring/):

> Grafana ships with built-in support for Google Cloud Monitoring. Add it as a data source to build dashboards for your Google Cloud Monitoring metrics.

GCP also might use [Prometheus](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/prometheus) features. Maybe this might give you something similar to what you want.

> Prometheus is a monitoring tool often used with Kubernetes. If you configure Cloud Operations for GKE and include Prometheus support, then the metrics that are generated by services using the Prometheus exposition format can be exported from the cluster and made visible as external metrics in Cloud Monitoring.

There are some workarounds, however they won't fulfill what you want.

- It is possible to create multiple conditions that identify the same issue. Every time a condition is met, a notification will be received.
- It is possible to get users notified when a condition is **NOT** met, however this might cause spam messages.

The last thing I want to mention is that there is already a `Feature Request` to add multiple notifications until the condition is gone. More details in [FR: Repeat Notifications until condition is gone](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153940230).

**Additional Documentation:**

- [Monitoring Alerts in GCP by integrating Cloud Operations with Notification Channels](https://medium.com/cloudwithmore/mayday-mayday-mayday-95fb5d2e46e0)

**Conclusion**

- Alert policies that are created through Google Cloud Console send a notification only when the condition is met. You can also enable notification to get solved notification.
- There is `Feature Request` to add repeatedly notifications - [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153940230)
- To send notifications to other apps/resources you can use `Webhooks` or `PubSub`.